# My Python XML DOM Parser, cannot parse valid XML

Tags: python, xml, parsing, soap

I am currently trying to build a simple python script to automate a tedious task of logging into a SOAP XML based webservice, calling the same method a number of times and lastly logging out.

However I am running into issues constructing xml DOM simply getting parser errors.

Following is the code I'm currently working with.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import http.client
import urllib.parse
import xml.dom.minidom

class soap_consumer:

        def __init__(self, msg, json=False):
                self.msg = msg
                self.json = json

        def envelope(self):
                if self.json:
                        return self.msg
                else:
                        doc = xml.dom.minidom.Document()
                        env = doc.createElement('soapenv:Envelope')
                        env.setAttribute('xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance')
                        env.setAttribute('xmlns:xsd', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema')
                        env.setAttribute('xmlns:soapenv', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')
                        env.setAttribute('xmlns:urn', 'urn:packetfront_becs')

                        print(self.msg)

                        #XML input request data
                        rawdom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(self.msg)
                        messagenode = rawdom.firstChild

                        #Header
                        header = doc.createElement('soapenv:Header')
                        env.appendChild(header)

                        #Body
                        body = doc.createElement('soapenv:Body')
                        body.appendChild(messagenode)

                        env.appendChild(body)
                        doc.appendChild(env)

                        print(doc.toxml('utf-8'))

                        return doc.toxml('utf-8')

        def send_request(self, url, port, path, content_type, accept, https=False):
                data = self.envelope()

                print(data)
                print(len(data))

                headers = {"Content-type" : content_type, "Accept": accept, "Content-length": len(data)}
                conn = ''

                conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(url, port)

                print(conn)
                conn.request("POST", path, data, headers)

                response = conn.getresponse()
                resp_data = response.read()

                print(resp_data)

                if response.status == 200:
                        conn.close()
                        return resp_data
                else:
                        return 'Failed:' + str(response.status) + str(resp_data)
                        

login_req = """
<urn:sessionLogin soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <in xsi:type="urn:sessionLoginIn">
    <!--You may enter the following 3 items in any order-->
    <username xsi:type="xsd:string">USERNAME</username>
    <password xsi:type="xsd:string">PASSWORD</password>
  </in>
</urn:sessionLogin>
"""

sw_login_req = soap_consumer(login_req)
sw_resp = sw_login_req.send_request(url='URL-REDACTED', port='80', path='/', content_type='application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8', accept='text/xml')
```

But I'm getting a parsing error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./update_interfaces.py", line 148, in <module>
    sw_resp = sw_login_req.send_request(url='URL REDACTED', port='4490', path='/', content_type='application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8', accept='text/xml')
  File "./update_interfaces.py", line 46, in send_request
    data = self.envelope()
  File "./update_interfaces.py", line 27, in envelope
    rawdom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(self.msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1968, in parseString
    return expatbuilder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 925, in parseString
    return builder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString
    parser.Parse(string, True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: unbound prefix: line 2, column 0
```

I have tested the raw XML via postman and it is working as expected, shown below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:packetfront_becs">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <request xsi:type="urn:requestHeader">
         <!--You may enter the following 2 items in any order-->
         <sessionid xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
      </request>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:sessionLogin soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <in xsi:type="urn:sessionLoginIn">
            <!--You may enter the following 3 items in any order-->
            <username xsi:type="xsd:string">USERNAME</username>
            <password xsi:type="xsd:string">PASSWORD</password>
         </in>
      </urn:sessionLogin>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What am I doing wrong here?